# Jenkins access file in workspace - groovy postbuild

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to access an XML config file in a Jenkins workspace and parse it with the Groovy XmlSlurper via the groovy post build plugin.  I am able to access the File by creating a FilePath object, but XmlSlurper is expecting either a File object or a String.  There is a toString method for FilePath, but it looks like it is deprecated.

Has anyone done something similar to this?

```
def project = manager.build.project
def fp = project.getWorkspace().child("summary.xml");

if (fp.exists()) {
        def perfData = new XmlSlurper().parse(fp)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to [use readToString](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html#readToString%28%29):

```
    def perfData = new XmlSlurper().parseText(fp.readToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

I see FilePath has a

```
 InputStream read()
 String readToString()
```

Either one of those should get you to the format you need. InputStream.getText() in Groovy returns the content of the stream.